# How to display all available custom post categories in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, categories

How to display all categories of a custom post type on home screen without listing the items.

I already created the custom post type and it's categories, now I need to display all the categories on my home page as links to the each category page. Can someone help please?

Comment: Have a look on [second answer of this post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14331/get-terms-by-taxonomy-and-post-type#answer-14334).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
            $terms = get_terms( 'taxonamy_name', array(
                'orderby'    => 'count',
                'hide_empty' => 0
            ) );
                foreach($terms as $term)
                {
                echo $term->name;
                }?>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use now [get_categories](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_categories/)

Here is an example of code:

```
<?php
   $args = array(
               'taxonomy'         => 'Your Taxonomy Name',
               'hide_empty'       => 0,
               'orderby'          => 'name'
           );

   $cats = get_categories($args);

   foreach($cats as $cat) {
?>
       <a href="<?php echo get_category_link($cat->slug); ?>">
           <?php echo $cat->name; ?>
       </a>
<?php
   }
?>
```

**Remember** write your taxonomy name as you registered, in here `'Your Taxonomy Name'`

e.g. `product_cat`, `blog_cat` etc

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Correction: Comma (,) is missed after 'taxonomy' => 'Your Taxonomy Name' so throws error.

Comment: wow ... After 6 years .. :D :D

Answer (score 1):

```
$cat_args = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'your-custom-post', // your custom post type
);
$custom_terms = get_categories($cat_args);
echo print_r($custom_terms);
```

Comment: This is wrong. The taxonomy paramter expects no post type. See here ->[get_categories](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_categories/)

Answer (score -1):

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => 10 );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
      the_title();
    echo '<div class="entry-content">';
       the_content();
    echo '</div>';
endwhile;
```

Comment: This will list the items of the custom posttype, not the categories of it.